# SQL Aliasing / Join Conundrum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Hello fair people of the Internet!

A quick question for the genial geniuses of the board if I may...

I'm trying to 'filter' (for want of a better term) results in a dataset, and it is essentially a situation whereby we have an ID for the group and then a collective ID.  Might be easier to just say a 'Tenant Ref' and a 'Tenancy Ref', seeing as that is what I'm working with!

I have been able to sort of get what I'm after, albeit in a doubtlessly inelegant fashion and well...not as I need, as there are duplications.

As the data I'm working with is steeped in confidentiality, I can't post any of the data, but here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

Pr.Ref             AS PPROPERTYID,
Ty.GlobalReference AS PPREVREF,
Ty.Tenancy_Id      AS TenancyId,
Tt1.Tenant_Id       AS TenantId,
Tt1.Title           AS Title,
Tt1.Forename + ' ' +

CASE
  WHEN Tt1.Middlename IS NULL
  THEN ''
  ELSE Tt1.Middlename
 END               AS FirstName,

Tt1.Surname         AS Surname,
Tt1.LandPhone       AS HomePhone,
Tt1.Mobile          AS Mobile,
Tt1.EMail           AS Email,
Tt2.Title           AS Title2,
Tt2.Forename + ' ' +

CASE
  WHEN Tt2.Middlename IS NULL
  THEN ''
  ELSE Tt2.Middlename
 END               AS FirstName2,

Tt2.Surname         AS Surname2,
Tt3.Title           AS Title3,
Tt3.Forename + ' ' +

CASE
  WHEN Tt3.Middlename IS NULL
  THEN ''
  ELSE Tt3.Middlename
 END               AS FirstName3,

Tt3.Surname         AS Surname3,
Tt4.Title           AS Title4,
Tt4.Forename + ' ' +

CASE
  WHEN Tt4.Middlename IS NULL
  THEN ''
  ELSE Tt4.Middlename
 END               AS FirstName4,

Tt4.Surname         AS Surname4,
Tt5.Title           AS Title5,
Tt5.Forename + ' ' +

CASE
  WHEN Tt5.Middlename IS NULL
  THEN ''
  ELSE Tt5.Middlename
 END               AS FirstName5,

Tt5.Surname         AS Surname5,
Tt6.Title           AS Title6,
Tt6.Forename + ' ' +

CASE
  WHEN Tt6.Middlename IS NULL
  THEN ''
  ELSE Tt6.Middlename
 END               AS FirstName6,

Tt6.Surname         AS Surname6,


'END1234'          AS 'END1234'

FROM Tenancy Ty

LEFT JOIN Tenancies Tys    ON Ty.Tenancies_Id  = Tys.Tenancies_Id
LEFT JOIN Property Pr      ON Tys.Property_Id  = Pr.Property_Id
LEFT JOIN Landlords LLs    ON Pr.Property_Id   = LLs.Property_Id
LEFT JOIN LandlordJoin LLJ ON LLs.Landlords_Id = LLJ.Landlords_Id1
LEFT JOIN Tenants Tts      ON Ty.Tenancy_Id    = Tts.Tenancy_Id
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt        ON Tts.Tenants_Id   = Tt.Tenants_Id
LEFT JOIN Conditions Con   ON Ty.Tenancy_Id    = Con.Tenancy_Id
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt1       ON Tts.Tenants_Id = Tt1.Tenants_Id 
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt2       ON Tts.Tenants_Id = Tt2.Tenants_Id AND Tt2.Tenant_Id <> Tt1.Tenant_Id
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt3       ON Tts.Tenants_Id = Tt3.Tenants_Id AND Tt3.Tenant_Id <> Tt2.Tenant_Id AND Tt3.Tenant_Id <> Tt1.Tenant_Id
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt4       ON Tts.Tenants_Id = Tt4.Tenants_Id AND Tt4.Tenant_Id <> Tt3.Tenant_Id AND Tt4.Tenant_Id <> Tt2.Tenant_Id 
                                                          AND Tt4.Tenant_Id <> Tt1.Tenant_Id
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt5       ON Tts.Tenants_Id = Tt5.Tenants_Id AND Tt5.Tenant_Id <> Tt4.Tenant_Id AND Tt5.Tenant_Id <> Tt3.Tenant_Id 
                                                          AND Tt5.Tenant_Id <> Tt2.Tenant_Id AND Tt5.Tenant_Id <> Tt1.Tenant_Id
LEFT JOIN Tenant Tt6       ON Tts.Tenants_Id = Tt6.Tenants_Id AND Tt6.Tenant_Id <> Tt5.Tenant_Id AND Tt6.Tenant_Id <> Tt4.Tenant_Id 
                                                          AND Tt6.Tenant_Id <> Tt3.Tenant_Id AND Tt6.Tenant_Id <> Tt2.Tenant_Id 
                                                          AND Tt6.Tenant_Id <> Tt1.Tenant_Id
```

Keep in mind that this is a bit of a 'working copy', so apologies for the ugliness and sheer messiness of the join apocalypse!

Has anyone got any pointers as to why the results might be transposing the values (where more than one Tenant_Id is linked to a single Tenancy_Id)?  The query does seem to be returning the correct number of tenants, but is duplicating the rows...whereas I'm hoping for a nice, tidy single row with the tenant values neatly displayed in corresponding columns.

Thank you all in advance - and apologies if there is an undue level of inanity owing to a caffeine intake which would be more inline with that of a small town than a single person!

Rob

Comment: Please read about MVCEs in the Help section. In particular: please give some example input, output and desired output example data, and a simpler query with the same problem including DDL.

Comment: Your paragraph about filtering is unclear. Please explain clearly about group vs collective and tenant refs vs tenancy refs.

Comment: It seems that your problem is at the cardinality level, but since we don't have any clue on cardinality of tables i.e. if the same id can be found several times as a reference in a table and you are using this ID to join another table, it will multiply all the records.  What I do in cases like this is query on a specific dataset and put one join at a time to see where records start getting multiplied... then you can fix that portion of the query by adding a subquery.  All this is theory, but if you would be able to setup a similar example with bogus data, we would be able to help you more.